# null pointer exception in button declaration

Tags: android

in this line am getting NullPointerException can any one help me to fix this

```
Button up[]; 
up[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.adultup1);
up[0].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {}
```

Comment: but a breakpoint in the second line and launch the application in debug mode. See what it's null, (up or R.id.adultup1) and solve it using one of the answers below. I think you're getting the nullpointer in the up variable.

Answer (score 3):

You need to allocate the Button array, e.g.

```
up = new Button[10];
```